Looking up users through Graph API fails with "reference-property objects are not present"
I am trying to look up users through Graph API version 6.5.0 with the following code:
graphClient.users().byUserId("userId@thedomain.dk").get()

but my lookup fails with
com.microsoft.graph.models.odataerrors.ODataError: Resource 'userId@thedomain.dk' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

I can create calendar events in the users outlook calender using code like this:
graphClient.users()
            .byUserId("userId@thedomain.dk")
            .calendar()
            .events()
            .post(theEvent);

I am guessing that it is the "one of its queried reference-property objects are not present"-part that is the issue. I have no clue what that means though.
I have the following permissions set on the application client I am using:

Application.Read.All
Calendars.Read
Calendars.ReadWrite
User.Read
User.Read.All


Do the user exists in Azure Active Directory/Microsoft Entra ID tenant? Verify this by logging into the Azure Portal and in the users blade

How did you create the user? Do the user exist in the tenant or not?

@Rukmini. The fact that I can create calendar events on the user does not mean that the user exists in the Active Directory tenant?

The Azure Portal belongs to a customer, so I don't have access.

The user must exist in the AAD tenant to perform the action and hence you are getting the error "Resource 'userId@thedomain.dk' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

Then please check if the user exists in the tenant if its another tenant user you can also try to configure the application as Multitenant and perform the action

@Rukmini. I have forwarded your suggestions/questions to my customer.  I still don't understand how I am able to create calendar events on the user if it does not exist in the tenant AAD.

Sorry my bad I misread, But the error occurs only if the user is not present and are you passing the UPN or Email of the user?

And also if you have user ID pass the ID and try

Any update on the issue?

The error "Resource  'xxx@xxx.xxx' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present" usually occurs if the user you are querying is not present in the Microsoft Entra ID tenant.


As you stated you are able to create the calendar events by passing the UPN of the user it might be the issue that you are not passing valid UPN for the user API call.

In my environment, I created a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted User.Read.All API permission which is required to call user API.

I used the below code and able to successfully get user details using Microsoft Graph API version 6.5.0:
package com.example;

import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.serviceclient.GraphServiceClient;

public class GraphApiExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String clientId = "ClientID";
        final String tenantId = "TenantID";
        final String clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        final String userId = "ruk@XXX.onmicrosoft.com";

        final String[] scopes = new String[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        final ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .build();

        if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected error");
        }
        final GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);

        try {
            // Get the user by userId (email or userPrincipalName)
            User user = graphClient.users().byUserId(userId).get();

            System.out.println("User ID: " + user.getId());
            System.out.println("User Display Name: " + user.getDisplayName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


If still the issue persists, check the below:

Make sure that you are passing the User Principal Name of the user:



Or try to pass the Object ID of the user to query instead of UPN.
Ensure that the user exists and is correctly configured in the Azure AD as If the user doesn't exist in Azure Active Directory, you will get this error. You can double-check if the user exists.
Double-check the user’s existence using Microsoft Graph Explorer.
Check if you are querying a user by email not by UPN instead.
If the user belongs to another tenant, then configure the application and multitenant and try.

Otherwise, try to call UserCollectionResponse result = graphClient.users().get(); API which lists all users in the tenant (instead of waiting for the customer) and check if the user you are querying exists. This API will work as you have User.Read.All API permission granted to the application.
